# How to prevent NetBeans from generating context.xml when opening a web application project?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

In NetBeans 8.1 I created a new project of the kind "Web Application with Existing Sources". I deleted context.xml in META-INF because I don't want it there (I have my reasons). But whenever I restart NetBeans or just close and reopen the project, NetBeans generates the context.xml file again. Is there any way to avoid it? I've tried to search but without any success. Thanks for help!

Comment: Do you need it as a web application? Have you tried just opening the project as a standard project?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I've just tried but then I can't see the content of the 'web' folder in netbeans at all. In a web project the 'web' folder is at the same level as the 'src' folder and Nebeans displays it's content under the 'Web Pages' node. But in a standard project, there is no 'Web Pages' node of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found if I edited the Project Properties for the project, and removed 'Tomcat' from the selected "Server" field under the "Run" tab, netbeans stopped creating context.xml.

I may have also removed this line manually from nb-configuration.xml:

```
        <org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_deploy_2e_server>Tomcat</org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_deploy_2e_server>
```

I'm not sure if that's necessary or not though, my guess is it's not, but feel free to experiment and comment below or edit this answer if you figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't figured out a way to stop it from regenerating, but I have at least figured out a workaround (using maven) to stop it from *using* the generated file (which is what was really causing headaches). I just overwrite the generated context.xml with a test context.xml file (yes, for this workaround you need to have *some* kind of context.xml file somewhere). I also need to exclude the test context.xml file from the production war file.

My test context.xml file is checked in to src/test/webapp/META-INF/context.xml. I want it copied to the target directory (overwriting the generated file) but not included in the war file. So in my pom.xml, I've configured the maven-war-plugin like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.3</version>
  <configuration>
    <webResources>
      <resource>
        <!-- location of context.xml used for integration tests -->
        <directory>src/test/webapp/META-INF</directory>
        <!-- setting stuff in the test file, you might not need this -->
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <!-- overwrites the context.xml file generated by Netbeans -->
        <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>
      </resource>
    </webResources>
    <!-- don't include test context.xml with the war file -->
    <packagingExcludes>META-INF/context.xml</packagingExcludes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I know this doesn't answer the question about how to stop regenerating the file, but if your situation was like mine then it may still help.